# Apply with automatic weights

Tags: rigging

I have often found help on this forum, but this is the first time I actually got a question I could not find an answer to. I applied the armature shown below on the mesh with automatic weights. Of course the mesh was on the armature when I did this. But after I applied it this happens. ANY ideas?

I unchecked deform on the main bones, the IK's and the elbow and knee bones, and the bones show in the same direction.

[image]

Comment: Hard to say for sure basing only on your description and the image, but it looks like the mesh didn't have applied rotation/location/scale in the center of the scene/the same place as the armature.

Comment: I applied scale ond rotation bevore, but when I try to apply the location the origin point just moovs away, in the oposite direction and the same lenght the mesh does when the Armature is applied, so I think this is the reason. Bur how do I avoid the Origin point's mooving?

Comment: If you applied everything before parenting the mesh to the armature, then that's not the reason. If you did it after, then it is.